# How to get NSImage format and alpha in swift?

Tags: swift, nsimage

I have an NSImage in my app, and I need to get its format and find out if it has an alpha channel. The only information I managed to retrieve is the image size.

(I get image with a drop and drag system)

`@State var image = NSImage(named: "image")`

```
if self.image?.size.width == 1024 && self.image?.size.height == 1024 {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing about `NSImage` is that it can store multiple representations, each of which may be in a different format. For example, you could have one representation as PDF vector artwork, and then, a few bitmap versions of the same image to display at various scales (i.e. one for standard, one for Retina, etc.). So there *isn't* really one format for an `NSImage`.

You *can* loop through its `.representations` and look at those, though. These are of type `NSImageRep`, and contain more information about the image (for example, it has a `hasAlpha` property that can tell you whether the representation has an alpha channel or not).

If you want more information than `NSImageRep` provides, the good news is that it's an abstract superclass, which has a bunch of concrete subclasses for certain types of images. For example, you can check its class using `as?` to see if it's an `NSBitmapImageRep`, `NSPDFImageRep`, `NSCIImageRep`, etc. Once you have the representation cast to one of its subclasses, you'll get a lot more options for looking at the image data (`NSBitmapImageRep` is the most common one you'll see for non-vector image data).

If you *really* want to get into the nitty-gritty, both `NSImage` and `NSImageRep` have methods to convert to a `CGImage`, where you can use all the low-level CoreGraphics functions on it.